# How to write an integration test in JAVA

Tags: java, integration-testing, spring-restcontroller

i'm learning yet testing in java and i'm trying to write an integration test for controller below:

```
    public class OrderController {

    @Autowired
    private OrderService orderService;


    public OrderController(OrderService service) {
        this.orderService = service;
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/add")
    @ApiOperation(value = "Add", response = AddOrderResult.class)
    public Response<AddOrderResult> add(@ModelAttribute AddUpdateOrderEnter enter) {
        return new Response<>(orderService.addOrder(enter));
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/addOrderParts")
    @ApiOperation(value = "AddOrderParts", response = GeneralResult.class)
    public Response<GeneralResult> AddOrderParts(@ModelAttribute @ApiParam("请求参数") AddOrderPartsEnter enter) {
        return new Response<>(orderService.AddOrderParts(enter));
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/list")
    @ApiOperation(value = "Order List", response = OrderDetailsResult.class)
    public Response<List<OrderDetailsResult>> list(@ModelAttribute @ApiParam("请求参数") GeneralEnter enter) {
        return new Response<>(orderService.getOrderList(enter));
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/details")
    @ApiOperation(value = "Order Details", response = OrderDetailsResult.class)
    public Response<OrderDetailsResult> details(@ModelAttribute @ApiParam("请求参数") IdEnter enter) {
        return new Response<>(orderService.getOrderDetails(enter));
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/delete")
    @ApiOperation(value = "delete", response = GeneralResult.class)
    public Response<GeneralResult> delete(@ModelAttribute IdEnter enter) {
        return new Response<>(orderService.deleteOrder(enter));
    }
}
```

My test file which i'm stuck:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
class OrderControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private OrderService service;


    private MockMvc mockMvc;


    @Test
    void shouldAddNewOrder() throws Exception {
    
    }
```

So i want to have some example to how to test my controller in integration way. Thnks for helps :)

Comment: This is a highly open ended question without one good answer. If you google "Spring Boot Writing Integration Tests" you'll find lots of articles that talk about best practices and such. That would be a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

What i've done is below:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(controllers = OrderControllerTest.class)

class OrderControllerTest {

    @MockBean
    private OrderService service;

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;


    @Test
    void shouldAddNewOrder() throws Exception {
        AddUpdateOrderEnter enter =  new OrderBuilder()
                .orderId(1L)
                .orderType(1)
                .productId(2L)
                .paymentTypeId("STRIPE")
                .build();

        mockMvc.perform(post("/order/add")
                .contentType("application/json"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
        ArgumentCaptor<AddUpdateOrderEnter> orderCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(AddUpdateOrderEnter.class);
        verify(service, times(1)).addOrder(orderCaptor.capture());
        assertThat(orderCaptor.getValue().getOrderId()).isEqualTo(1L);
        assertThat(orderCaptor.getValue().getOrderType()).isEqualTo(1);

    }
```

Comment: ok so far...now: 1. prepare an `AddOrderResult` object (which your mocked service pretends to return) 2. instruct your mock (`when(service.addOrder(...)...`) to return addorderresult (form 1.) 3. add a `.body(enter)` to your `mockMvc.perform()...` 4. (optional) verify the result matches 1.

Comment: thanks. i get this error now when i run my test : java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

Answer (score 0):

```java
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class OrderControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private OrderService orderService;

    @Test
    public void testAddOrder() throws Exception {
        AddUpdateOrderEnter enter = new AddUpdateOrderEnter();
        AddOrderResult expectedResult = new AddOrderResult();
        when(orderService.addOrder(any(AddUpdateOrderEnter.class))).thenReturn(expectedResult);

        MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/add")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content())
                .andReturn();

        assertEquals(200, result.getResponse().getStatus());
    }

}
```